# drawRect suddenly stops being called

Tags: macos, cocoa, opengl

Using XCode 5.1 with custom OpenGL view.
I have a separate thread that processes data and calls setNeedsDisplay to refresh the display.

This is working well, but sometimes after running for a while and using other apps, when I return to my app, drawRect of the OpenGL view is stopped being called.
I see that setNeedsDisplay is being called and, drawRect is called whenever I resize the window.

Can anyone suggest a solution or at least a way to track down the reason for the sudden change in this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

To whoever might be interested: 
Seems like calling setNeedsDisplay from another thread might cause problems, together with a high frequency of these calls.
I've significantly lowered the amount of calls to setNeedsDisplay and changed the calls to performSelectorOnMainThread and it seems to solve the probem.